# AS3 cancel event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hey so I have an MC with multiple buttons in it, I can drag the container MC, when I release the MC I want to cancel any MouseEvent.CLICK listeners that may have fired during. mouseEnabled and mouseChildren is not an option for my current problem, thanks.

Comment: The buttons are held inside another object class I would prefer to keep them independent of each other, i.e the buttons may also live outside of the container. I was hoping there was a global way to cancel any MouseEvent.CLICK events.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use an option to intercept events of container from travelling to child while dragging?

Add listener to container, and stop propagation on those events, using capture phase.

Comment: when I stop dragging the container on the mouseup handler I want to check if the container moved or not. If it did I need to cancel any CLICK event that may have occurred when the user clicked on the container, if not then the user intended to click the button (tap) and not drag the container. (I would use some tolerance to gauge if it was dragged or tapped, maybe there is a better way!)